# How to parse multi dimensional JSON data through Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

How could i parse this type of json data, getting in "results" to fetch single values like zipcode, state etc

```
{
    "row": [
        {
        "id": "5",
        "name": "test",
        "email": "test@test.com",
        "street": "mystreet",
        "city": "mycity",
        "state": "mystate",
        "zipcode": "123456",
        "myimage": "image.gif"}
    ]
}​
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

first,  you need to parse that string with [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

```
var myJson = JSON.parse(the_raw_data_string);
```

it ends up into an object like this:

```
var myJson = {
    "row": [
        {
        "id": "5",
        "name": "test",
        "email": "test@test.com",
        "street": "mystreet",
        "city": "mycity",
        "state": "mystate",
        "zipcode": "123456",
        "myimage": "image.gif"}
    ]
}​
```

accessing the items:

```
myJson.row[0].id
myJson.row[0].name
myJson.row[0].street
//and so on...
```

Answer (score 9):

you can take the json result to a var like follows

```
var json = {
    "row": [
        {
        "id": "5",
        "name": "test",
        "email": "test@test.com",
        "street": "mystreet",
        "city": "mycity",
        "state": "mystate",
        "zipcode": "123456",
        "myimage": "image.gif"}
    ]
}​
```

then get the result to another

```
var result = json.row;
```

then you can iterate through the result

```
for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
    var object = result[i];
    for (property in object) {
        var value = object[property];
        alert(property + "=" + value); // This alerts "id=5",  etc..
    }
}
```

hope this will help you

Answer (score 2):

Again here jQuery is your good friend

I have posted [a sample using jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sJHxR/) with multiple records in your data row

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var result = {
    "row": [
        {
        "id": "5",
        "name": "test",
        "email": "test@test.com",
        "street": "mystreet",
        "city": "mycity",
        "state": "mystate",
        "zipcode": "123456",
        "myimage": "image.gif"
        },
        {
        "id": "10",
        "name": "test2",
        "email": "test2@test.com",
        "street": "mystreet2",
        "city": "mycity2",
        "state": "mystate2",
        "zipcode": "7891011",
        "myimage": "image.gif"
        }
    ]
};

var oE = $("#output");
$.each(result.row, function(index, value) {
  //- extract target value like zipCode
  oE.append($("<li></li>").text(value.zipcode));

            });
});
​
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

If the json data is **raw** then use **json.parse.** 
After that to loop the multi dimensional json data.

```
data = {"employees":[
    { "firstName":"Anushka", "lastName":"shetty" },
    { "firstName":"Shreya", "lastName":"Saran" },
    { "firstName":"Kajal", "lastName":"Agarwal" }
]};

for (var key in data.employees) {   
    alert(data.employees[key].firstName) //alert Anushka, Shreya, Kajal
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use JQuery each function:

```
$.each(myData.row, function(index,item) {
  // here you can extract the data
  alert (item.zipcode);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `JSON.parse(jsonstring)`. Then iterate over the objects/arrays.