# Error in handling json data inside jquery ajax each function

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, each

Have a good day programmers

**Description :**
 I have dropdown in my code whenever user select some category i need to search that value from json file. I done this thru change event it's working well.

```
$('#social_media').on('change',function(e){
        var test = this.value;
        $.ajax({
        url:"jsoncontent.json",
        dataType:"json",
        success:function(data){
            //here test variable contain 'facebook' value
            //so i gave data.test instead of data.facebook
            $.each(data.test,function(key,value){               
                    alert(value.name);
                });     
            }   
        });
    });
```

**Problem :** Here's my problem in each loop i gave ***data.test*** instead of ***'data.facebook'*** because test is the variable which contain value ***'facebook***' and i know data is the object and test is the variable and sure i did mistake in handling object and variable..this is my json data

```
{
    "StackOverflow": [
        {
            "name": "StackOverflow",
            "exp": "3month",
            "username": "koushik",
            "Designation": "Software Developer"
        },
        {
            "name": "StackOverflow",
            "exp": "3month",
            "username": "koushik",
            "Designation": "Software Developer"
        },
        {
            "name": "StackOverflow",
            "exp": "3month",
            "username": "koushik",
            "Designation": "Software Developer"
        },
        {
            "name": "StackOverflow",
            "exp": "3month",
            "username": "koushik",
            "Designation": "Software Developer"
        }
    ],
    "facebook": [
        {
            "name": "facebook",
            "exp": "3month",
            "username": "koushik",
            "Designation": "Software Developer"
        },
        {
            "name": "facebook",
            "exp": "3month",
            "username": "koushik",
            "Designation": "Software Developer"
        },
        {
            "name": "facebook",
            "exp": "3month",
            "username": "koushik",
            "Designation": "Software Developer"
        },
        {
            "name": "facebook",
            "exp": "3month",
            "username": "koushik",
            "Designation": "Software Developer"
        }
    ],
    "twitter": [
        {
            "name": "twitter",
            "exp": "3month",
            "username": "koushik",
            "Designation": "Software Developer"
        },
        {
            "name": "twitter",
            "exp": "3month",
            "username": "koushik",
            "Designation": "Software Developer"
        },
        {
            "name": "twitter",
            "exp": "3month",
            "username": "koushik",
            "Designation": "Software Developer"
        },
        {
            "name": "twitter",
            "exp": "3month",
            "username": "koushik",
            "Designation": "Software Developer"
        }
    ]
}
```

Thank in advance

Comment: Just have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10084234/how-to-parse-multi-dimensional-json-data-through-javascript

for your better understanding of how to access multidimensinal JSOn data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$.each(data[test], function (key, value) {
    alert(value.name);
});
}
```

If `test` is a variable, then we use `data[test]` not `data.test`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create another `$.each` inside of the first `$.each`
So the second `$.each` should take the value of 'value'

```
$.each(obj, (key, value) {
           $.each(obj, (keys, values) {}
           }
```

It's something like that, as far I think.