# Returning all values that contain a particular key in nested JSON?

Tags: javascript, json

I have nested JSON as below:

```
{
    "fields": {
        "type": "custom",
        "level1": {
            "type": "custom"
        },
        "level2": {
            "type": "custom",
            "level3": {
                "type": "custom"
            },
            "level31": {
                "type": "notcustom"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to extract all the values that have the key `type`

The output I would like is:

```
{
    "fields":"custom",
    "level1":"custom",
    "level2":"custom"
}
```

Comment: mm..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10084234/how-to-parse-multi-dimensional-json-data-through-javascript

Comment: check this: http://blog.wax-o.com/2014/01/how-to-find-deep-and-get-parent-in-javascript-nested-objects-with-recursive-functions-and-the-reference-concept-level-beginner/

Comment: what if 'fields' object contains nested fields obj, which in turns contains nested 'fields' object and some of them contain property `type` on their level? you wouldn't know what is what...

Comment: You would need to use a stack. This is a [DFS problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to be simple using a recursive approach. At first checking whether it's an object or not. If its an object again call the function passing that object.

Else checking that key and appropriate value is there. Populating it in result object and returning it.

```js
    var object = {
      "fields": {
        "type": "custom",
        "level1": {
          "type": "custom"
        },
        "level2": {
          "type": "custom",
          "level3": {
            "type": "custom"
          },
          "level31": {
            "type": "notcustom"
          }
        }
      }
    };

    function recursiveIterator(object, needle, value, result) {
      var result = result || {};

      for (var key in object) {
        if (object[key][needle] === value) {
          result[key] = object[key][needle];
        }

        if (typeof object[key] === "object") {
          recursiveIterator(object[key], needle, value, result);
        }
      }

      return result;
    }

    document.getElementById("result").textContent = JSON.stringify(recursiveIterator(object, "type", "custom"));
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

It's a very generic approach. You can pass `key` such as `type` in this case and what value you want to match, `custom` in this case.

Comment: using a recursive function solves it but isn't there a function to parse the json to find it. This works fine with my question but wanted to know if there is a direct approach. I have a very huge json containing around 400 fields in a multidimentional json. If I use a recursive aprroach will it not consume more time and reduce the performance?

Answer (score 0):

You need a [recursive function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_function) to navigate the tree structure.

The following code snippet does it, and it adds the results to an array of custom fields.

**I've not removed sub-properties of custom fields, so if a custom field had a sub-level property, the property is also included**. You could remove these sub-properties but you would modify the source object tree too. Thus, this can be solved creating clones with `Object.create` and removing the whole properties afterwards... but I believe that the whole code is enough to open your mind and understand how you would solve the issue.

Run the snippet to see the JSON result live!

### Update

*Although you requested an object as a result (something like a dictionary after all), I suggest that array result should work better in this scenario, because if there's more than a "level" property called the same way (for example, two `level1` properties), only the last one would be accessible in the result because it might be overwritten.*

```js
var obj = {
    "fields": {
        "type": "custom",
            "level1": {
            "type": "custom"
        },
            "level2": {
            "type": "custom",
                "level3": {
                "type": "custom"
            },
                "level31": {
                "type": "notcustom"
            }
        }
    }
};

function getCustomFields(field, customFields) {
    var customFields = typeof customFields != "undefined" ? customFields : [];

    if (field["type"] == "custom") {
        customFields.push(field);
    }

    // Object.keys gets all own object property names as an array
    // in order to use filter to do a "where" the fieldName starts with
    // "level" word. Once every "level" property is filtered, you execute
    // an Array.forEach to execute the enclosing functin against the
    // inner level giving each level field and current customFields array
    // to accumulate results...
    Object.keys(field).filter(function (fieldName) {
        return fieldName.indexOf("level") == 0;
    }).forEach(function (levelPropertyName) {
        getCustomFields(field[levelPropertyName], customFields);
    });
    
    return customFields;
}

var customFields = getCustomFields(obj.fields);

document.getElementById("result").textContent = JSON.stringify(customFields);
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```